# Why does the print speed change at specific height? (Using Ultimaker Cura slicer)

Tags: ultimaker-cura, speed

I'm trying to figure out why the print speed changes at one point in this model.

I'm using Ultimaker Cura 3.6 and, as shown in the picture, I set the speed to be the same across the entire print. Is there a setting I'm missing?

[image: Screenshot of Ultimaker Cura 3.6 with sliced model]

[image]

0scar is right. Changing the minimum time per layer to 1s (from 3s), makes the entire print print at the same speed, as per settings. However, it's probably a bad idea:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not being able to see the rest of the model (from the first image), if looks as if the light green sliced area displaying a lower speed for the top of the cylinder, is the only part that need to be printed to that height (now confirmed in the second image). This speed reduction is done by the slicer and is not specifically caused by Ultimaker Cura (other slicers do result in similar behavior). Note this is a good thing! Lets explain.

Filament needs an amount of time to cool before the next layer is deposited onto the previous layer. When the layers get small (surface area) and there are no other layers the print head shifts to, the print process is slowed down to allow the filament to cool down; hence you see a decrease in print speed.  If you deposit too fast, the last part of your print will become too hot and will deform.

A print parameter that influences the behavior is the `Minimal Layer Time` parameter in Ultimaker Cura, please read the hint information of this parameter:

[image: Hint text of Minimal Layer Time parameter of Ultimaker Cura]

Comment: Yup! Just tried and that's the cause. Thanks again!